# Power BI - Display a Value based on two dimensions in the same visual

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to figure out how to structure my dataset such that someone can have a visual with the same value based on two dimensions.
Very simplified example:

```
Main table
Working Attorney (Person)
Billing Attorney (Person)
City
Revenue
Cost
etc...
```

There are many more Dimensions, values and measures, but this is enough to make my point.

I can create a visual that is:

```
WorkingAttorney  City  State  Country  sum(Revenue) sum(Cost)
```

And I can create one that is:

```
BillingAttorney  City  State  Country  sum(Revenue) sum(Cost)
```

However, I have been asked, since the same person can be the billing attorney in one situation and a working attorney in another, or even both at the same time, can we create a single visual that has both?
Essential, if these were SQL tables, I would just full outer join on the Working Attorney = Billing Attorney and then be able to display the 4 values.

```
Attorney  City  State  Country sum(Revenue as Working Attorney) sum(Cost as Working Attorney) sum(Revenue as Billing Attorney) sum(Cost as Billing Attorney)
```

Hopefully this example is still a little more concrete?

Not sure the best way to do this. Perhaps there is a better way to structure my dataset?

What I think I want to avoid is having to create a measure for every value specific to each dimension, because that seems unmanageable.

Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example? I can't quite tell what you are trying to do.

Comment: I updated the question, does that help?

Comment: Creating another table with Attorney as primary key and adding 4 calculated columns(sum/cost as billing/working attorney)

Comment: I can help you with this but like Attorneys I charge for my services in 6 minute intervals.  BTW my time for writing this comment was 6 minutes and will be included in my first bill ... just kidding ...

Answer (score 0):

I just posted a blog about doing exactly this. Select a name on a slicer and it filters your results on where that name could appear in multiple columns.

https://bisamurai.wordpress.com/2018/03/02/filtering-on-multiple-columns-using-one-slicer/

Hope this helps.